# Record voice narration with on the fly editing capabilities

Tags: audio, recording, voice

I would like to record myself reading a daily devotional passage. However, my reading skills are not good enough to read it straight through without stuttering or mispronouncing something.

I'd like to find a solution that gives me the ability to quickly cut the sound file (probably by viewing the sound wave and using a slider) and then restart recording (amend) at the spot I messed up at. I would also like to do it for free or spend very little money.

Comment: Personally I would just carry on talking after I'd messed up - just skip back to the beginning of the sentence, then cut out the bad bits after I had done all the speaking.  It makes for better fluidity of speech.  Editing immediately you mess up can cause your speech to sound broken and unnatural.  With Audacity (detailed below) you can chop out the bad bits at the end of the recording session.

Comment: Agreed with @Matt, try to keep it as fluent as possible and just keep talking. I once was in a radio studio where they recorded an audio book or something and that's what they did there too.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using [Audacity](http://audacity.sourceforge.net/)? It's free and available for all major platforms. And it has a record function, some built-in effects and filters.

[image]